# Rendering broken when using setViewportTransform to flip y-axis (fabric.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

In our project, we are converting complex image objects that use a different coordinate system ([0,0] = bottom left) into fabric.js objects. We tried to use `setViewportTransform` with a negative value on the scale y in order to achieve this but encountered some strange behaviour.

For example, given this code:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
const path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0L 0 100 L 100 100 z');
canvas.add(path);
canvas.setViewportTransform([1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 300]);
```

When you try to move the `path` around, in certain locations it completely disappears.

Are we doing something wrong or is there another way to achieve what we are looking for?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/niiyeboah/ry4Lqn3f/) is a fiddle showing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.
Use `flipY`property to flip the content and addapt the top position.
http://jsfiddle.net/ejmw1sbp/

Comment: We ended up using this approach. Thanks!